# Compound subjects and compound sentences

Tags: compound-sentences, compound-subjects, compound-predicates

Is this a compound sentence? 'John and Hary sang well.'

This sentence can be resolved into two independent clauses: John sang well, and Hary sang well.

Wren and Martin grammar says that if a sentence with compound subject can be resolved into two independent clauses, it's a compound sentence. But I'm confused. Please clarify how to distinguish between simple and compound sentences when compound subjects or compound verbs have been used.

Comment: Are you clear about this now?

Answer (score 1):

> [1]  *John and Harry sang well*.
>
> [2] *John sang well and Harry sang well*.

A lower-level distributive coordination like that in [1] can be expanded into a logically equivalent main-clause one, as in [2].

But that doesn't mean that [1] is a compound sentence; it's not. It's a simple sentence with one subject, "John and Harry", and the single predicate "sang well".

Comment: Can you help [over here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/206325/catenative-clause-and-canonical-clause)???

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is simple as it forms one complete idea.

The so-called "compound subject" is termed as  "[homogeneous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homogeneous)" subjects.

As about the definition of  compound sentences look [this](https://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-a-compound-sentence-examples-definition-quiz.html) : 
A ***compound*** sentence is a sentence that has at least ***two independent clauses*** joined by a comma, semicolon or conjunction.

An independent clause is a clause that has a subject and verb and forms a complete thought. 
An example of a compound sentence is, 'This house is too expensive, and that house is too small.'